# Python regex exclude Underscore

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all two-char sumbols in UNICODE, except underscore. Current solutin is:

```
pattern = re.compile(ur'(?:\s*)(\w{2})(?:\s*)', re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print pattern.findall('a b c ab cd vs sd a a_ _r')
['ab', 'cd', 'vs', 'sd', 'a_', '_r']
```

I need to exclude underscore _ from regex, so **a_** AND **_r** are not found. The problem is, my characters can be in any language. So i can't use regex like this: [^a-zA-Z]. For example, in russian:

```
print pattern.findall(u'ф_')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exclude anything that's a non-word char AND _

```
[^\W_]
```

instead of

```
\w
```

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet would be to use the new [`regex` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) instead. One of it's features is that it can *remove* characters from a character set:

```
import regex as re

pattern = re.compile(ur'(?:\s*)([\w--_]{2})(?:\s*)', re.UNICODE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

The `[\w--_]` syntax creates a character set that is the same as `\w` with the underscore character removed from the matching characters.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
a="Exclude_from_search"
re.search("(\w[^_]+)", a).group(0)
'Exclude'
```